# Display page based on the option that is being selected using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp

Requirement: I have a drop down list where based on the option selected the appropriate content should get displayed

HTML:

```
<label class="col-md-0" for="Role">
    <br>Role: </label>
<select name="role" id="roleType">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Now based on the option I select appropriate content should get displayed.A person can have multiple roles.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: SO is not a place to have someone do your work (or homework) for you. Tell us what did you try and why it didn't work and then some can help. 
Then maybe someone can help you, otherwise it's just throwing some piece of codes as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you need some sort of tab functionality for your page, does this help you?

If it is you can augment this code, to suit your requirement!

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  
  app.controller('TabController', function() {
    
    this.role = 'A';

    this.setTab = function(tabId) {
      this.tab = tabId;
    };

    this.isSet = function(tabId) {
      return this.tab === tabId;
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
    <select name="role" id="roleType" ng-model="tab.role" ng-change="tab.setTab(tab.role)" ng-init="tab.setTab(tab.role)">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>

    <div ng-show="tab.isSet('A')">
      <h4>Tab 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="tab.isSet('B')">
      <h4>Tab 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="tab.isSet('C')">
      <h4>Tab 3</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple roles means your `select` needs a `multiple` attribute.
So, your `ngModel` must be an array.

Then, you can check if a value is present in the bound array using [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-init="role = []">
  <!-- label[for] must match select[id] -->
  <label class="col-md-0" for="roleType">Role:</label>
  <!-- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select -->
  <select name="role" id="roleType" multiple ng-model="role">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>

  <!-- consider using ng-if instead of ng-show/ng-hide, if needed -->
  <div ng-hide="role.indexOf('A') === -1">Content A</div>
  <div ng-hide="role.indexOf('B') === -1">Content B</div>
  <div ng-hide="role.indexOf('C') === -1">Content C</div>
</div>
```